# Getting Information of devices which are connected to my network using python

Tags: python, ip, ping

I am using this code for getting ip of same network:

```
import sh    

for num in range(1,10):  
    ip = "192.168.4.0"+str(num)  

    try:  
        sh.ping(ip, "-c 1",_out="/dev/null")  
        print ("PING",ip , "OK")  
    except sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:  
        print ("PING", ip, "FAILED")
```

It gives IP of connected devices but I want complete information of each connected device.

Comment: what is *complete information of each connected device*? all open ports? or what?

Comment: yes, device name and open ports

Comment: what commands would you use on the command line to do that? you could get the DNS name using [`socket.gethostname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html?highlight=gethostname#socket.gethostname).